# generalised leibnitz theorem

Tags: calculus

I am aware of the leibnitz theorem when we are finding the nth derivate of the product of two functions of x which are possessing derivatives of the nth order.I tried to find an expression for the case when the number of functions in the product is more than two.

for the case $k=3$

$$(uvw)_n=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom nr u_{n-r} (vw)_{r}$$ where $u_r$ denote the $rth$ derivate and $u_0=u$

Now $$(vw)_r=\sum_{p=0}^r \binom rp v_{r-p}w_p$$

And so $$(uvw)_n=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom nr u_{n-r} \sum_{p=0}^r \binom rp v_{r-p}w_p$$

I couldnot simply this and generalise this for more than $3$ functions.Any ideas?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 can you please explain how it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ derivatives to divide onto $3$ functions. If $u$ gets $i$ derivatives, $v$ gets $j$ derivatives, and $w$ gets $k$ derivatives, then there are $\frac {n!}{i!j!k!}$ ways this can be done. Therefore,
$$D^n (uvw) = \sum \frac {n!}{i!j!k!} (D^iu)(D^jv)(D^kw) $$
where the sum us taken over $i, j,k=0,\ldots,n $ and $i+j+k=n $.